# To form clusters based on the condition?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The sample input file(the actual input file contains about 50,000 entries):

```
615 146 
615 180 
615 53  
615 42  
615 52  
615 52  
615 51  
615 45  
615 49
616 34
616 44
616 42
616 41
616 42
617 42
617 43
617 42
685 33
685 33
685 33
686 33
686 33
687 47
687 68
737 449
737 41
737 1138
738 46
738 53
```

I must compare each value in column with same values like 615,615,615 must be grouped together the cluster must contain column1 value like 146,180.....45,49 then the cluster must break & form the another cluster for next set of same values 616,616,616..........so on

The code which i wrote was:

```
from __future__ import division
from sys import exit
h = 0
historyjobs = []
targetjobs = []


def quickzh(zhlistsub,
    targetjobs=targetjobs,num=0,denom=0):

 li = [] ; ji = []
 j = 0
 for i in zhlistsub:
    x1 = targetjobs[j][0]

    x = targetjobs[i][0]

    num += x
    denom += 1
    if x1 >= 0.9 * (num/denom):#to group all items with same value in column 0 
      li.append(targetjobs[i][1])
    else:
      break     
 return li


 def filewr(listli):
 global h
 s = open("newout1","a")
 if(len(listli) != 0):
      h += 1
      s.write("cluster: %d"%h)
      s.write("\n")
      s.write(str(listli))
      s.write("\n\n")
 else:
      print "0"


def new(inputfile,
historyjobs=historyjobs,targetjobs=targetjobs):
zhlistsub = [];zhlist = []
k = 0 

with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        job = map(int,line.split())
        targetjobs.append(job)
    while True: 
     if len(targetjobs) != 0:

       zhlistsub = [i for i, element in enumerate(targetjobs)]

       if zhlistsub:
          listrun = quickzh(zhlistsub)
          filewr(listrun)
       historyjobs.append(targetjobs.pop(0))
       k += 1
     else:
         break

new('newfinal1')
```

output which i got is:

```
 cluster: 1
 [146, 180, 53, 42, 52, 52, 51, 45, 49, 34, 44, 42, 41, 42, 42, 43, 42, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 47, 68, 449, 41, 1138, 46, 53]

 cluster: 2
 [180, 53, 42, 52, 52, 51, 45, 49, 34, 44, 42, 41, 42, 42, 43, 42, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 47, 68, 449, 41, 1138, 46, 53]

 cluster: 3
 [53, 42, 52, 52, 51, 45, 49, 34, 44, 42, 41, 42, 42, 43, 42, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 47, 68, 449, 41, 1138, 46, 53]
 ..................so on
```

But the output that i require is:

```
  cluster: 1
  [146, 180, 53, 42, 52, 52, 51, 45, 49]
  cluster: 2
  [34, 44, 42, 41, 42]
  cluster: 3
  [42, 43, 42]
  _____________________ so on
```

So can anyone suggest what changes should i made to condition to obtain the required result .It would be really helpful ?

Comment: I'm having a real tough time understanding what you need... but usually for grouping, `itertools.groupby` or `collections.defaultdict` is the way to go...

Answer (score 1):

Try this, [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) takes care of creating the clusters, all that's left to do is building the lists:

```
import itertools as it
[[y[1] for y in x[1]] for x in it.groupby(data, key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

The above assumes that `data` is where your input resides, and that it's already filtered and sorted by the first column. For the example in the question it looks like this:

```
data = [[615, 146], [615, 180], [615, 53] ... ]
```

Comment: can u please suggest some condition in the place of my if condition `if x1 >= 0.9 * (num/denom):` to provide the result.

Comment: My answer helps with building the clusters, but it's not clear how you're filtering the values with that condition. I can only suggest that you split the problem in two, first filter out the input, build a list as `data` in my example, and afterwards build the clusters using the above list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

have not tested the answer but follow this concept

```
import collections.defaultdict

cluster=defaultdict(list)

with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        clus, val = line.split()
        cluster[clus].append(val)

for clus, val in cluster:
    print "cluster" +str(clus)+"\n"
    print str(val)+"\n"
```